# Is opening a tab in duckduckgo browser in Android considered safe from data leaks?

Tags: privacy, android, duckduckgo

I use ColorOS (based on Android 12) and DuckDuckGo browser 5.145.4.

I want to know if opening a tab in DuckDuckGo browser to my mailbox online can leak sensitive data. In my case, it's a French server hosted by OVH with Outlook.

Any advice? My main concern is potential data steal/leak from Google.

Comment: Welcome to the community. What's your threat model?

Comment: Edited my post. GAFAM is my main concern

Comment: "GAFAM" really only has meaning in French. And that doesn't explain what you are concerned about. Who, in *your* scenario would leak anything?

Comment: The question can be resumed as: is google can slurp/spy my emails from my duckduckgo browser?

Comment: From Android? sure, it is ***possible*** but unlikely, but that has nothing to do with the browser. How would Google get their hands on any data aside from the device itself? We can't speak for the server-side; they could be doing anything.